# Classifying Cyclic $R$-Modules (Up To Isomorphism) where $R$ is Commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know that if two $R$-modules are isomorphic i.e. $M_1=Rm_1, M_2=Rm_2$ and $Rm_1\cong Rm_2$ then we have that $R/Ann(m_1)\cong R/Ann(m_2)$(Ann(m) is just the set of annihilators of $m$). Since $R$ is commutative this implies that $Ann(m_1)=Ann(m_2)$. Also, for any ideal $I$ of $R$ we have a cyclic $R$-module i.e. $R/I=R(1+I)$ and $Ann(1+I)=I$. Hence, the set of equivalent classes of isomorphic cyclic $R$-modules is in bijection with the ideals of $R$.

Does anyone know if that is the correct classification?

Comment: Yes, the cyclic modules are quotients of the ring.  For noncommutative rings with identity  it is the same but with right ideals (for cyclic right modules), but you may have redundancy.